# How to remove ".\" when pressing tab on terminal of VSCode Java?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm compiling a java program, but pressing on the tab it says `.\FirstProgram.java` instead of `FirstProgram.java` (without the `.\` symbols).

```
foo\bar> java .\FirstProgram.java
```

instead of

```
foo\bar> java FirstProgram.java
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow! Please don't post pictures of code. Rather, write a snippet and use the "`" character to write it out.

Comment: They both are the same.  The second one implicit means the FirstProgram is in the working or current directory while the first one explicitly include the working directory.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but should help some readers.
the `.` means current folder/directory (depends on OS).
the `..` means parent folder/directory.
in some OSs you also have `~/` for home directory etc'.
when you refer to a file as `./file` then it is the file in the current folder.
when you refer to a file as `file` then depending on the OS it could be either a file on the systems path or the file in the current folder or something else.
So, the shell you are using in vS-code conforms to the common way of referencing a file on the local folder.

note that if there is a way to remove it, it will be by changing/tweaking the shell that the terminal uses.